# JSONObject new version <20200518> get("key") method gives wrong jsonObject

Tags: java, json, spring, maven

In my java web application, recently upgraded the JSON version to **20200518** which resulted in jsonObject.get("key") resulted in wrong format as given below.

**The jsonObject (version 20160810)** [Expected result]

```
jsonObject.get("key") = {JSONObject@1234}{"name":"VAL","value":"val"} //[*Expected format*]
```

**The jsonObject (version 20160810)**

```
jsonObject.get("key") = {CustomizedClass$SubClassType} "val" //[*Wrong format*]
```

This gives an issue to jsonObject.toString() method gives

"key":"BUY"  instead  "key":{"name":"BUY","value":"buy"}

```
public class CustomizedClass {
    public CustomizedClass() {
        super(SubClassType.class);
    }
}
```

```
public static enum SubClassType {
        BUY("buy")
        
        private String valueAsString;
        
        public String getName() {
            return this.name();
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return this.valueAsString;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return this.valueAsString;
        }
}
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

[image: Image of current (version 20160810) [wrong] json format]

[image: Image of Expected (version 20160810) Json Format]

Comment: 1) Which library is that? --- 2) What package is `CustomizedClass` in? --- 3) What does the JSON text look like?

Comment: 1) Json library is --> org.json 2) new  JSONObject(object) -> gives the my customized class type. Expected a HashMap with second screen shot format

Comment: In that case, which part of this has anything to do with `spring`?

Comment: It is a spring web application, and new json version added in maven dependency resulted this difference

Comment: You never answered: What package is `CustomizedClass` in? --- If the class is yours, then show it to us.

Comment: It is an autogenerated class (written in some business logic) created after "new JSONObject(object)" and only JSON version upgradation resulted this difference.

Comment: public class CustomizedClass {
    public CustomizedClass() {
        super(SubClassType.class);
    }
}

 public static enum SubClassType {
        BUY("buy")
  
        private String valueAsString;
  
        public String getName() {
            return this.name();
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return this.valueAsString;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return this.valueAsString;
        }
}

Comment: Please check above class CustomizedClass and enum  SubClassType

Comment: Don't post code in a comment. **Edit** the question and show code there, adequately formatted.

Comment: How was the `jsonObject` that you call `get("key")` on created? In particular, how was the `key` added? --- Instead of having to pull the information out of you one piece at a time, please read [How to create a **Minimal**, **Reproducible** Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then fix the question.

Comment: JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(object); The same code running on lower version will give results as we expect